# How to make Terminal open in fullscreen and homebrew and do a script using Applescript

Tags: java, terminal, applescript, homebrew

I'm trying to write a script in Applescript to open Terminal in fullscreen and homebrew style, and then make Terminal execute a java program i wrote. That program will then work in Terminal (no GUI).

Here is my code so far. I have been able to make Terminal go fullscreen and type in the command, but i cannot make it homebrew

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd 'desktop/java/Amerika'; javac 'Amerika.java'; java 'Amerika'"
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "f" using {control down, command down}
   end tell
end tell
```

Here is another script, which if i add it to the previous one, simply opens a new Terminal window in homebrew, sometimes fullscreen, sometimes not

```
tell application "System Events"
   tell process "Terminal"
      tell menu item "Homebrew" of menu "New Window" of menu item "New Window" of   menu "Shell" of menu bar item "Shell" of menu bar 1
          click
       end tell
   end tell
end tell
```

The first code also has some problems, since it opens a fullscreen Terminal sometimes, and sometimes it doesnt.

Is there anyway to make Terminal open in fullscreen and homebrew style then execute something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work: (a bit much boiler plate but surely you can extract the things you need)

Please note that you can't go into fullscreen BEFORE executing the script because that won't work.

```
if my UIscript_check(true) then

    if my do_submenu("Terminal", "Shell", "New Window", "Homebrew") then

        tell application "Terminal"

            -- here your script --
            do script "echo " & quoted form of "this is my script" in window 1

        end tell

        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "f" using {control down, command down}
        end tell

    else
        beep
    end if

end if


on do_menu(app_name, menu_name, menu_item)
    try
        -- bring the target application to the front
        tell application app_name
            activate
        end tell
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process app_name
                tell menu bar 1
                    tell menu bar item menu_name
                        tell menu menu_name
                            click menu item menu_item
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
        return true
    on error error_message
        return false
    end try
end do_menu

on do_submenu(app_name, menu_name, menu_item, submenu_item)
    try
        -- bring the target application to the front
        tell application app_name
            activate
        end tell
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process app_name
                tell menu bar 1
                    tell menu bar item menu_name
                        tell menu menu_name
                            tell menu item menu_item
                                tell menu menu_item
                                    click menu item submenu_item
                                end tell
                            end tell
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
        return true
    on error error_message
        return false
    end try
end do_submenu

on UIscript_check(with_msg)
    -- get the system version
    set the hexData to system attribute "sysv"
    set hexString to {}
    repeat 4 times
        set hexString to ((hexData mod 16) as string) & hexString
        set hexData to hexData div 16
    end repeat
    set the OS_version to the hexString as string
    if the OS_version is less than "1030" then
        display dialog "This script requires the installation of Mac OS X 10.3 or higher." buttons {"Cancel"} default button 1 with icon 2
    end if
    -- check to see if assistive devices is enabled
    tell application "System Events"
        set UI_enabled to UI elements enabled
    end tell
    if UI_enabled is false then
        if (with_msg) then
            tell application "System Preferences"
                activate
                set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
                display dialog "This script utilizes the built-in Graphic User Interface Scripting architecture of Mac OS X which is currently disabled." & return & return & "You can activate GUI Scripting by selecting the checkbox \"Enable access for assistive devices\" in the Universal Access preference pane." with icon 1 buttons {"OK"} default button 1
            end tell
        end if
        return false
    else
        return true
    end if
end UIscript_check
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the current settings property:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "uptime"
    set current settings of result to settings set "Homebrew"
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "f" using {control down, command down}
end tell
```

Comment: A bit slower (or maybe its just my computer), but also works. Thanks!